# MVC4 javascript file location

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-ajax

I am trying to create MVC4 application. The scaffolded scripts contained  older jquery so I updated it to 1.10 but corresponding mvc4 file unobtrusive-ajax.js seems to stop working as it is using live() instead of on()

Where can i find jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js for jquery-1.10.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the latest jquery unobtrusive on NuGet. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax/